# Custom Batch File from Scratch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am tasked with creating a batch file that will do the following:

1) Start Windows Firewall Service
2) Add Entries into Windows Firewall to block network access to some Network Locations
3) Delete the mapped Network Drive

I have got the following command line scripts which do these tasks individually. However, I am not sure how I can put all of them into a single batch file which will do the steps one after the other.

```
net stop <Service-Name>

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IP Block" dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=<IP_Address>/32

net use x: /delete
```

Can someone please guide on how do I put these commands into a batch file which will simply execute when I run it.

Thanks.

Comment: it's scripting, not programming. Just add the commands to a file named `<somename>.bat` the same as you would enter them at command line (well, there are some specials but they don't apply with your simple commands). Be sure to choose coding "ANSI" when you save the file.

Answer (score 0):

### Just place the commands into a text file with the file extention of `.bat`.

#### Each command gets its own line.

---

Below is an example of your file with command line arguments. `%1`, `%2`, `%n` each indicate the position of the command line argument.
E.G. `%1` is the first argument, `%2` is the second and so on.

```
net stop %1
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IP Block" dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=%2/32
net use x: /delete
```

You can execute the batch file with the command line arguments:

```
ScriptName.bat ServiceName 123.123.123.123
```

And it will execute as follows:

```
net stop ServiceName
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IP Block" dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=123.123.123.123/32
net use x: /delete
```

---

Hard coded example:

`ScriptName.bat`:

```
net stop wuauserv
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IP Block" dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=192.168.0.1/32
net use x: /delete
```

To execute it, just call the file name:

```
ScriptName.bat
```

Cheers!